# select data and if duplicate id add (sum) the data

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, distinct, case

I am using TSQL to select data from the database. I want to select all data in a table but if the id is a duplicate add (sum) all column 'a' with same ID and make it just 1 row.

There should be no duplicate IDs in the output.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT id,a,b FROM dbo.test WHERE 
   id not in (select id from dbo.test) CASE a WHEN a + a??
```

example:

```
dbo.test
========
id  a  
1   4  
1   5 
2   3
3   2

output:

1 9 <-- two ids of 1 so column 'a' is added together.
2 3
3 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(a) as a, SUM(b) as B
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
```

This is what grouping and aggregation is designed for!

**FYI, this is how aggregation works:**

When you group and aggregate fields, you are combining records into a single row.

In  your OP, you wanted to see a `SUM` of `A` for every value of `ID`. That's what the original query I posted does.

You also want to include `B`, which is a `varchar` field, according to your comments.

In that case, you need to decide what to do with `B`.  Since you are grouping multiple rows together, there are (potentially) multiple values of `B` per value of `ID`.  You need to either:

- Group by `B` as well, which will add extra rows
- Apply an aggregation such as `MAX()`, `MIN()`, etc. to `B`
- Exclude `B` from the results list.

Comment: I get a "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" error. If I also group by column B, it works, but I dont want to group by B. Only ID.

Comment: Error. B is varchar. Should I HAVING COUNT > 1?

Comment: What do you want to do with `B`?  You can get a `MAX` if you just need any `B` record associated with the `ID`.

Comment: I do not want to touch B. It should remain untouched per row. Only A should change if the ID is the same.

Comment: I don't think you understand how aggregation works, then.  I'll post an edit to explain for you.

Comment: @Alexey - if you want to post an answer, please do so.  Don't put it as a comment on MY answer.

Comment: @JNK I've come up with this only after reading comment "I do not want to touch B. It should remain untouched per row. Only A should change if the ID is the same." which happend to be a comment to your answer, so I decided not to make a new answer, because it wouldn't be obvious why I did so since your answer is already appropriate for OP.